# Get TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex when filtering dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to filter the dataframe by a certain datatime period like the following code.

```
df2 = df2['Dates'].between_time(pandas.to_datetime('5/13/2015 8:41'), pandas.to_datetime('5/13/2015 8:55'))[['Dates','Category']]
```

but got an error 'TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex'
This is the dataframe

[image]

and I tried

df2 = pandas.read_csv(path2,parse_dates=[0])

like one of the response from other post but still got the same error.
Does anyone know what happen here?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter `df` by a certain datetime period, you can try with:

```
start_date = pandas.to_datetime('5/13/2015 8:41')
end_date = pandas.to_datetime('5/13/2015 8:55')
df2.loc[(df2['Dates'] > start_date) & (df2['Dates'] < end_date)]
```

Answer (score 2):

As what you offer I think the index's is not the DatetimeIndex so you may try :

```
df2.index=pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example i had a df with different columns called "df_whole", one column had date time in this format: 2022-08-11 23:00:48:007.
I loaded it from a Cassandra db so it was already formatted.

These are the steps that I followed:

**1) Convert the date time column literally called 'datetime' in my df to a format that pandas likes**.

```
df_whole['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df_whole['datetime']))
```

**2) Take that column and give to the df the index**

```
df_whole.index = df_whole['datetime']
```

**3) Now use the filter:**

```
df_whole.between_time('14:00', '21:00')
```

job done!